# why doesn't the match version of the code compile, in F#

Tags: f#

here is some code:

```
type Test() =

    static member SomeValue =
        "AAA"

    static member test1 (a) =
        match a with
        | Test.SomeValue -> "a"
        | _              -> "b"

    static member test2 (a) =
        if a = Test.SomeValue then
            "a"
        else
            "b"
```

the *test1* version will not compile ([FS0039] The type 'Test' does not define the field, constructor or member 'SomeValue'.) while *test2* compiles.

Since *SomeValue* doesn't have any parameters, it will be evaluated once, making it a constant. Why doesn't the compiler accept it in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `test1` version you are using **Pattern Matching** thus you must provide a **pattern** after the pipe symbol (`|`).

But `Test.SomeValue` is a property, not a pattern, according to [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching).

So, to use Pattern Matching in you code, for example, you can mark `SomeValue` as a `Literal`:

```
type Test() =

    [<Literal>] static let SomeValue = "AAA"

    static member test1 (a) =
        match a with
        | SomeValue -> "a"
        | _         -> "b"

    static member test2 (a) =
        if a = SomeValue then
            "a"
        else
            "b"
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answer explains why you cannot match to a non build time constant.
But if you cannot have that value as constant, then you are looking for a [guard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/match-expressions#guards-on-patterns), which can operate on runtime values:

```
type Test() =

    static member SomeValue =
        "AAA"

    static member test1 (a) =
        match a with
        | x when x = Test.SomeValue -> "a"
        | _              -> "b"

    static member test2 (a) =
        if a = Test.SomeValue then
            "a"
        else
            "b"
```